# How to manage service in angular in large application?

Tags: angular, angular-services

I build a large angular application but it difficult for me to manage the service in the application. My question is which is the better way to manage service either make service in each component or make it single service to handle all the HTTP request?

Answer (score 1):

According to my practice, when I'm start a new project I create a new directory in app called `core` and inside the core directory again I make folder for `services` and I'll create all my service files with `ng generate servise SERVICE_NAME`. I create separate services for each feature/ function and name them according to their feature/ function. Services in Angular should be implemented with the single responsibility principle. (`auth.service.ts, user.service.ts, utils.service.ts, cart.service.ts, address.service.ts etc.`)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are working on a large project. My opinion is to have a separate module for API services which have individual service files for each feature. Example:

- APIServiceModule

  - auth.service.ts
  - project.service.ts
  - user.service.ts
  - so on...